# I can't decrypt text

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, encoding

I have url [http://translate.google.ru/translate_a/t?client=x&text=ввійти вийти&sl=ua&tl=en](http://translate.google.ru/translate_a/t?client=x&text=%D0%B2%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8%20%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8&sl=ua&tl=en)

**If you will go through this link in response you will have js file with normal translate text:**

```
{"sentences":[{"trans":"enter exit","orig":"ввійти вийти","translit":"","src_translit":"vviy̆ty vyy̆ty"}],"src":"uk","server_time":127}
```

But if you get this data through program you will have encrypt translate data:

```
{"sentences":[{"trans":"\u00D0 \u00B2 \u00D0 \u00B2 \u00D1-\u00D0 \u00B9 \u00D1,
 \u00D0 \u00B8 \u00D0 \u00B2 \u00D0 \u00B8 \u00D0 \u00B9 \u00D1, \u00D0 \u00B8",
"orig":"\u00D0\u00B2\u00D0\u00B2\u00D1?\u00D0\u00B9\u00D1?\u00D0\u00B8 \u00D0\u0
0B2\u00D0\u00B8\u00D0\u00B9\u00D1?\u00D0\u00B8","translit":"","src_translit":""}
],"src":"is","server_time":4}
```

Through this  code i got this data.

```
string url = @"http://translate.google.ru/translate_a/t?client=x&text=ввійти вийти&sl=ua&tl=en";
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Timeout = 5000;
            WebResponse responce = request.GetResponse();
            Stream stream = responce.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader st = new StreamReader(stream);
            string responsText = st.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(responsText);
            Console.ReadLine();
```

How can i decrypt this data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data is not encrypted. It is encoded. If you use proper JSON deserialization, like the DataJsonContractSerializer class, this will not be a problem, because the framework will decode the data for you.

```
[DataContract]
public class TranslationData {
    [DataMember(Name = "sentences")]
    public Sentence[] Sentences { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "src")]
    public string Source { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "server_time")]
    public int ServerTime { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Sentence {
    [DataMember(Name = "trans")]
    public string Translation { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "orig")]
    public string Original { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "translit")]
    public string Transliteration { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "src_translit")]
    public string SourceTransliteration { get; set; }
}
```

Then use the `System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer` class for deserialization *(you have to add a reference to the `System.Runtime.Serialization` assembly)* to read from the response stream directly:

```
var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(TranslationData));
return (TranslationData)serializer.ReadObject(theResponseStream);
```

There are other ways of doing this, but this way you'll get nice typed data.

Comment: serializer hasn't method Deserialize()                          Error 1 'System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer' does not contain a definition for 'Deserialize' and no extension method 'Deserialize' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer' could be found

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit on the fast side there... It's `ReadObject` - not `Deserialize`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: are you sure that StringReader(whatTheServerReturned) maybe StreamReader. because i have next problem Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.IO.StringReader' to 'System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReader'

Comment: Check my updated response and deserialize directly from the Stream.